# Plugin Recommendation for selling one page content

Tags: plugins, membership

Hi I need a recommendation for a plugin, preferably free, that enables me to block a page's content. I only need this for a few pages, and the users must be able to buy the content on an individual page basis. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a membership plugin such as:

1. WPMU Dev Membership - http://premium.wpmudev.org/project/membership
2. Wishlist Member - http://member.wishlistproducts.com/

I've personally used both and they work great.

With these plugins, you would setup a membership level specifically for each page content you wish to sell. You can do one-time or recurring payments for your content as well.